# Gatsby - ReferenceError: Cannot access 'u' before initialization

Tags: reactjs, typescript, gatsby

I'm new to Gatsby, and I've been asked to add something to a Gatsby project, that isn't quite related to Gatsby. The dependency I had to add was not compatible with older versions of Gatsby, so I updated it to the latest version (^5.13.3). Thing is, when I ran `gatsby develop` the first time, I got an error that after looking into it, it resolved running `export NODE_OPTIONS=--no-experimental-fetch`, but after some changes, killing the execution (for other reasons) and running again `gatsby develop`, I started getting an error like this:

```
"gatsby-node.js" threw an error while running the onPreInit lifecycle:

Cannot access 'd' before initialization

   5 | import { rpcData } from "./src/hooks/useTenk"
   6 |
>  7 | export const onPreInit: GatsbyNode["onPreInit"] = async () => {
     |              ^
   8 |   const data = await rpcData()
   9 |   fs.writeFileSync(
  10 |     path.resolve('stale-data-from-build-time.json'),
```

and

```
"gatsby-node.js" threw an error while running the createPages lifecycle:

Cannot access 'u' before initialization

  13 | }
  14 |
> 15 | export const createPages: GatsbyNode["createPages"] = async ({ actions }) => {
     |              ^
  16 |   console.log(1, locales)
  17 |   locales.forEach(locale => {
  18 |     actions.createPage({
```

When running `gatsby develop` and going to localhost, I have 3 pages: "/404/", "/404.html" and "/". The site has a [locale].tsx file on `src/templates/[locale].tsx` and the createPages loads from there like this, but since it's failing, it is not loading.

```
export const createPages: GatsbyNode["createPages"] = async ({ actions }) => {
  console.log(1, locales)
  locales.forEach(locale => {
    actions.createPage({
      path: locale.id,
      component: path.resolve("src/templates/[locale].tsx"),
      context: { locale },
    })
  })
}
```

I find this error weird, since I'm not using a d or u variable in any place, and I wasn't able to find something online. Let me know if I can add some more code.